# Save a list of user ids to a mysql table

Tags: mysql, arrays

I need to save a list of user ids who viewed a page, streamed a song and / or downloaded it. What I do with the list is add to it and show it. I don't really need to save more info than that, and I came up with two solutions. Which one is better, or is there an even better solution I missed:

1. The KISS solution - 1 table with the primary key the song id and a text field for each of the three interactions above (view, download, stream) in which there will be a comma separated list of user ids. Adding to it will be just a concatenation operation.
2. The "best practice" solution - Have 3 tables with the primary key the song id and a field of user id that did the interaction. Each row has one user id and I could add stuff like date and other stuff.

One thing that makes me lean towards options 2 is that it may be easier to check whether the user has already voted on a song?

---

tl;dr version - Is it better to use a text field to save arrays as comma separated values, or have each item in the array in a separate table row.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Definitely the 2nd:

- You'll be able to scale your application as it grows
- It will be less programming language dependent
- You'll be able to make queries faster and cleaner
- **It will be less painful for any other programmer coding / debugging your application later**

Additionally, I'd add a new table called "operations" with their ID, so you can add different operations if you need later, storing the operation ID instead of a string on each row ("view", "download", "stream").

Comment: I'm always surprised how fast do I get a good answer... Thank you very much, I'll probably do that. Would you suggest using a stored procedure to handle all the overhead of the operations table, or do it in code?

Comment: That's a more subjective answer, I think. I personally do like stored procedures but never use them. Why? Because I don't like coding in SQL, that's all. But I do believe a strong DB should have all the logic in it, including Foreign Keys, contraints, and CRUD logic whenever possible.

Comment: I would go without stored procedures. What if application grows and someone decides to change the database engine. Are the stored procedures fully portable? Also, it's more readable to see what's happening inside a class method or two. And also 2: I didn't met anyone that likes coding in SQL.

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely better to have each item in a separate row.  Manipulating text fields has performance disadvantages by itself.  But if ever you want to find out which songs user 1234 has viewed/listened to/etc., you'd have to do something like

```
SELECT * FROM songactions WHERE userlist LIKE '%,1234,%' OR userlist LIKE '1234,%' OR userlist LIKE '%,1234' OR userlist='1234';
```

It'd be just horribly, horribly painful.

Comment: I actually though to manipulate this in code. But the select does look a bit bad :)